# Is it possible to move an item out of a std::set?

Tags: c++, c++11

If I have an object that only allows move-only semantics - is it possible to move items from a set? I can't seem to find a way to do this.

Comment: @cppguy The elements of a set are immutable, so swapping or moving shouldn't work.

Comment: @juanchopanza [This seem to work?](http://ideone.com/Z97Eve)

Comment: That works because `std::string` can fallback to copy semantics.

Comment: @juanchopanza Heh, I trust you :)

Comment: @Snps Here's [a better example](http://ideone.com/e0hNIX). It shows that the move calls the copy constructor, because the iterator is a `const_iterator` so you cannot get a non-const reference from it. If you comment out the copy constructor, it doesn't compile.

Comment: C++17 can do this via `extract` and `merge`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, it is not possible.  There is no way to get non-const access to elements in a `set`, and move requires non-const references.  Allowing non-const access would make it trivially easy to break the invariants for `set`.

Answer (score 19):

C++17 added a function [`std::set<>::extract`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/extract) that allows moving an object out of a set:

```
std::set<MoveOnlyType> s;
s.emplace(arg0, arg1, arg2); // only way to insert such move-only objects, since C++11
auto internal_node = s.extract(s.begin()); // internal_node no longer part of set, we can do with it what we want
MoveOnlyType m = std::move(internal_node.value()); // finally get the actual object out
```