# Move unique_ptr from set to set

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I can't seem to figure this out and have tried the suggestions in:

[Move `unique_ptr`s between sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30048648/move-unique-ptrs-between-sets)

[how to move an std::unique_ptr<> from one STL container to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661056/how-to-move-an-stdunique-ptr-from-one-stl-container-to-another)

I have two sets containing unique pointers:

```
std::set<std::unique_ptr<some_type>> s1, s2;
```

The pointers are of course unique but the values of some_type may or may not be, so after joining the s2 into s1, s1's size may be the same or as large as |s1 + s2|.

It seems like I should be able to do this:

```
move(s2.begin(), s2.end(), inserter(s1, s1.end()));
```

But this fails with clang++ 3.8 / g++ 5.4.

What am missing here?

Comment: Wait, do you want to compare the pointed-to values or the unique_ptr's? Assuming it's the former, you should be using a custom Compare template argument for your sets. Are you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work because a `std::set` only gives `const` access to its elements. There is no way to move something out of a `std::set`. See [Is it possible to move an item out of a std::set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25515284/is-it-possible-to-move-an-item-out-of-a-stdset)

There's no good way to do this in C++14, but in C++17 there is a `merge` method provided for this purpose, which simply rearranges the internal pointers of the data structures without copying or moving any elements:

```
s1.merge(s2);
```

A somewhat reasonable workaround in C++14 is to change `std::set<std::unique_ptr<T>>` to `std::map<T*, std::unique_ptr<T>>`. Then you can do:

```
while (!s1.empty()) {
    s2[s1.begin()->first] = std::move(s1.begin()->second);
    s1.erase(s1.begin());
}
```

Comment: Or you can use `shared_ptr` instead of `unique_ptr`.

Comment: And if you make sure to use `std::make_shared` to make them instead of the `std::shared_ptr` constructor, it shouldn't hurt perf/memory use/memory fragmentation as much (with `std::make_shared`, only a single allocation is required for the reference counting overhead and the object storage, while using `new` and `std::shared_ptr` means two allocations), so it will behave more like `unique_ptr` speed-wise.

Comment: Thanks for this good answer (and following comment). I did end up just using a shared_ptr after wrestling with it some more. Bonus mini rant: if no compilers can produce useful error messages (most of the time) for a language it is a language design flaw, not a compiler issue. Anyways its been fun using C++ again..

Answer (score 2):

Currently you're conflating set membership with ownership, and that's the source of the problem.

Solution: use sets of raw pointers, and move the ownership elsewhere.

---

Re the envisioned

```
move(s2.begin(), s2.end(), inserter(s1, s1.end()));
```

In the standard library `move` is just a glorified cast, it's not an action routine. The imperative name form is misleading. Think of `std::move` as `as_moveable`.

Answer (score 1):

In C++17 you could use [`std::set::merge`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/merge) to do what you want as in the example below:

```
std::set<std::unique_ptr<T>> s1, s2;
...
s1.merge(s2);
```

[**Live Demo**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/vcR38HffFr7p2noJ)

A C++11 work around, rather expensive though and a bit of a betrayal to `unique_ptr`'s notion, that would also require that your objects are copyable. Would be to copy the objects of the second `std::set` in new `std::unique_ptr`s that you are going to insert in your first set:

```
std::set<std::unique_ptr<T>> s1, s2;
...
for(auto &&e : s2) {
  s1.insert(std::make_unique<T>(*e));
}
s2.clear();
```

mind that at the end you would have to `clear` your second set in order to recover from the hangout caused by the wild parting of `std::unique_ptr`'s notion.

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b2fa9fdb5ffc40e)